# Running Python lasagne with CUDNN in Ubuntu 14.04 Linux

Tags: python-2.7, cuda, gpu, theano, lasagne

I am on a Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux machine with NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] [10de:0de1] (rev a1) graphic card.

I am trying to run `lasagne` package with GPU enabled, however by running 
`import lasagne.layers.dnn`, I get an ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ali/DiabeticRethinopathy/diabeticrethinopathy/dr2/src/lasagne-master/lasagne/layers/dnn.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImportError("dnn not available")  # pragma: no cover
ImportError: dnn not available
```

Currently, I have installed and successfully compiled all the `cuda_7.0.28_linux` samples as well as `cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v3.0-rc`.

```
python -c 'from theano.sandbox.cuda.dnn import dnn_available; print dnn_available(); print dnn_available.msg'
```

I get this output:

```
False
Device not supported by cuDNN
```

I am using `python 2.7` and used `pip` to install all these packages from their `tar.gz` files, which are downloaded from their repositories.

Comment: Have you used google: https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/issues/242

Comment: Yes. I have seen this. `cudnn` is installed and its sample is compiled correctly.

Comment: I've found the reason! Simply, my GPU cannot support cudNN! :((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem! My system's GPU cannot/is not supported by `cudNN`, unfortunately. :(